# Cloudformation: How to pass a string through cloudformation script into UserData?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-cloudformation

Cloudformation command:

`- aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name stackName --template-body file://cloudformation.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=keyName,ParameterValue=myKeys`

I need to paste env variable into UserData cloudformation sctipt. So at the end it would have             docker pull quay.io/apple/myRepo:myVarName

```
UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub |
        docker pull quay.io/apple/myRepo:master
```

Comment: `!Join [ ":", ["quay.io/apple/myRepo", !Ref myParameterName ] ]`

Comment: I see. But how to you actually pass it i? Can you share example?

Comment: Your post already  includes an example of passing parameter values through the CLI

Comment: Those names used in cf file too ofter and it sort of confusion. I would appreciate simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you executed `aws cloudformation create-stack` with the following parameters:

```
--parameters ParameterKey=keyName,ParameterValue=myKeys
```

in your template you need to have `Parameters` section:

```
Parameters:

  keyName:
    Type: String
```

Then in your `UserData` you would reference parameter `keyName` as follows:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub |
     param_value=${keyName}
```

Comment: Would it look like this if you would have to concatenate it? docker pull quay.io/repo/apple:${branchName}

Comment: @Sergio13 What do you mean that it does not work? Any error messages? What do your updated UserData and Parameters sections look like now?

Comment: No error messages, it stops execution at that line, and if I navigate to ec2 instance I have no access to that branchName var.

Comment: My code: Parameters:
  keyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the EC2 Instances
    Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
  branchName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  launchTemplate:
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        UserData:
          Fn::Base64: !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            docker pull quay.io/****/****:${branchName}

Comment: @Sergio13 Can you updated your question with all the new details, error messages? Alternatively you can make new question if you want.

Comment: You answer actually worked. The issue was with codefresh way to pass data into cf script. It just needed to be assigned into var before passing it

Comment: @Sergio13 Thanks for letting me know:-)